# MySql : Increase query execution time for pagination

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project which have a large set of data. The data are stored in a MySql Db.
I want to fetch records with pagination from few tables. One of the table is having over 2 millions of records which is causing the page to freeze for a very long time. Also sometimes the page is not able to load at all.

The query I'm using to fetch the records :

```
SELECT 
    EN.`MRN`,
    P.`FNAME`, 
    P.`LNAME`,
    P.`MI`,
    P.`SSC`,
    sum(EN.`AMOUNT`) AS `TOTAL_AMOUNT` 
FROM `table_1` AS EN 
INNER JOIN `table_2` AS P ON EN.`MRN` = P.`MRN` 
GROUP BY EN.`MRN`,P.`FNAME`, P.`LNAME`,P.`MI`,P.`SSC` 
HAVING sum(EN.`AMOUNT`) > 0 
ORDER BY P.`LNAME`
```

By this query I'm getting the total number of records for the pagination to work. Then I again run this query to get the actual records :

```
SELECT 
    EN.`MRN`,
    P.`FNAME`, 
    P.`LNAME`,
    P.`MI`,
    P.`SSC`,
    sum(EN.`AMOUNT`) AS `TOTAL_AMOUNT` 
FROM `table_1` AS EN 
INNER JOIN `table_2` AS P ON EN.`MRN` = P.`MRN` 
GROUP BY EN.`MRN`,P.`FNAME`, P.`LNAME`,P.`MI`,P.`SSC` 
HAVING sum(EN.`AMOUNT`) > 0 
ORDER BY P.`LNAME`
LIMIT 0, 100
```

How can I make this query to work faster. Because it takes a very long time execute the query for the first time to get total number of records.

Comment: Use Count to count the records its faster than select all results and then get the count.

SELECT count(*) FROM `table_1` AS EN 
INNER JOIN `table_2` AS P ON EN.`MRN` = P.`MRN` 
GROUP BY EN.`MRN`,P.`FNAME`, P.`LNAME`,P.`MI`,P.`SSC` 
HAVING sum(EN.`AMOUNT`) > 0 
ORDER BY P.`LNAME`

Comment: @pkdq did you check table `table_1` having indexing on column which you selects? if you didn't given indexing then give it to those column which you are using mostly. that will make your execution faster then now.

Comment: Are you using innodb or myisam tables?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to separate `total_amount` from the query because that is the only value involving all the records. You can call this when you load the page. I assume that all your records in `table_1` is valid.

```
SELECT sum(EN.`AMOUNT`) AS `TOTAL_AMOUNT` FROM `table_1` AS EN
HAVING sum(EN.`AMOUNT`) > 0
```

Then get the query result every time when you flip the page. This should only return 10 records starting from record 0.

```
SELECT 
EN.`MRN`,
P.`FNAME`, 
P.`LNAME`,
P.`MI`,
P.`SSC`
FROM `table_1` AS EN 
INNER JOIN `table_2` AS P ON EN.`MRN` = P.`MRN` 
GROUP BY EN.`MRN`,P.`FNAME`, P.`LNAME`,P.`MI`,P.`SSC` 
HAVING sum(EN.`AMOUNT`) > 0 
ORDER BY P.`LNAME`
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to make this faster:

- Use `EXPLAIN` to make sure your indices are set correctly / set the correct indices.
- Only execute the complicated query once using [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).
- Use the `TOTAL_AMOUNT` alias in your `HAVING` statement to avoid doing the calculation twice.

MySQL will do some optimizations and caching itself so they might not all have the same impact.